# Will my laptop be able to install ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, system

I want to install Ubuntu as my main OS, but I'm worried that it will not work and mess up my laptop.

Here are my specs:
[image: specs]

Also, I want to know if this will mess up things like wifi and speakers.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Just make a [usb flash drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) with [ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and reboot laptop. Then choose first boot drive USB Flash Drive and follow instructions on screen.
If you want to replace windows, ubuntu wizard will erace all hdd space, windows installation and **user files**.

If you need two OS on laptop, you have to choose other option from ubuntu menu.
[Here is explaned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)